# Is there a name for deductive systems that always have representable (finite) counterexamples for invalid inferences?

Tags: logic

Consider classical propositional logic and consider a conditional theorem of the form $\Gamma \models \varphi$ where $\Gamma$ is finite. Propositional logic is compact, but I want the concept I'm describing to be applicable to non-compact logics as well, so I'm insisting on finiteness in this example.

If $\Gamma \models \varphi$ is invalid, then there exists a valuation $v$ such that $v \models \Gamma$ and $v \not\models \varphi$. We can think of this valuation as simply a set $X$ of the variables that are true. $X$ is finite. Moreover, if the number of variables originally was countable, then $X$ can be *represented* as a finite string taken from a finite alphabet.

For first-order logic, if $\Gamma \models \varphi$ is invalid, there's no guarantee that a countermodel will be representable. A proof of $\Gamma \models \varphi$ would be convincing, but is too high a bar. It's entirely possible for $\varphi$ to be contingent given that $\Gamma$ is true.

However, we can come up with ad hoc logics that loosely resemble FOL that have this property.

Consider the fragment of FOL consisting of $\forall$-sentences only in FOL. In addition, I will restrict the allowable structures.

A structure $M$ must either have a finite domain or have $\mathbb{N}$ as a domain and all of its relations and functions must be definable in $\mathbb{N}$.

If $\Gamma \models \varphi$ is invalid in the ad hoc system given above, then there will be a countermodel that can be written down witnessing its failure.

The simpler example $\Gamma \models_\text{fin} \varphi$ that ranges over finite structures only also has this "representable counterexample" property.

So, does this property have a name?

Comment: Typically, we’d say the semantics is complete over finite models.

Comment: @MarkSaving I'm not necessarily insisting that the model be finite. I'm okay with building infinite structures out of definable sets of $\mathbb{N}$ or restricting attention to computable predicates and functions.

Comment: Hmm. I see. I will have to think a bit harder about this, but one answer could be that semantic entailment is computable.

Comment: @MarkSaving I think the right criterion actually is that $\models$ be **co-c.e.**, that is, that $\not\models$ be a c.e. relation. For instance, consider $\mathsf{FOL}$ with the general semantics vs. the finite-structures-only semantics (writing "$\models_f$" for the latter). Classical $\models$ is c.e. by the completeness theorem and not co-c.e. by Godel's theorem, while $\models_f$ is co-c.e. by the (trivial) finite model property in this context but not c.e. by Trakhtenbrot's theorem.

Comment: @NoahSchweber This makes sense to me. We would expect any logic with computable semantics to not be very expressive, since it would not be able to express Peano arithmetic. It is regrettable that a co-c.e. logic which isn’t c.e. would not have a semantically complete proof system which is computably verifiable.